# Почему перестал работать async?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Вот весь мой код:

```py
from webserver import keep_alive
import json
import sqlite3
import re
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import datetime
import random
import asyncio
import config
import pymongo as mg
import discord as ds
import math

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=ds.Intents.all())

def str_time_to_seconds(str_time, language='ru'):
    conv_dict = {
        'w': 'weeks',
        'week': 'weeks',
        'weeks': 'weeks',
        'н': 'weeks',
        'нед': 'weeks',
        'неделя': 'weeks',
        'недели': 'weeks',
        'недель': 'weeks',
        'неделю': 'weeks',

        'd': 'days',
        'day': 'days',
        'days': 'days',
        'д': 'days',
        'день': 'days',
        'дня': 'days',
        'дней': 'days',

        'h': 'hours',
        'h': 'hours',
        'hour': 'hours',
        'hours': 'hours',
        'ч': 'hours',
        'час': 'hours',
        'часа': 'hours',
        'часов': 'hours',

        'm': 'minutes',
        'min': 'minutes',
        'mins': 'minutes',
        'minute': 'minutes',
        'minutes': 'minutes',
        'мин': 'minutes',
        'минута': 'minutes',
        'минуту': 'minutes',
        'минуты': 'minutes',
        'минут': 'minutes',

        's': 'seconds',
        'sec': 'seconds',
        'secs': 'seconds',
        'second': 'seconds',
        'seconds': 'seconds',
        'сек': 'seconds',
        'секунда': 'seconds',
        'секунду': 'seconds',
        'секунды': 'seconds',
        'секунд': 'seconds'
    }

    pat = r'[0-9]+[w|week|weeks|н|нед|неделя|недели|недель|неделю|d|day|days|д|день|дня|дней|h|hour|hours|ч|час|часа|часов|min|mins|minute|minutes|мин|минута|минуту|минуты|минут|s|sec|secs|second|seconds|c|сек|секунда|секунду|секунды|секунд]{1}'
    def timestr_to_dict(tstr):
        return {conv_dict[p[-1]]: int(p[:-1]) for p in re.findall(pat, str_time)}

    def timestr_to_seconds(tstr):
        return datetime.timedelta(**timestr_to_dict(tstr)).total_seconds()

    def plural(n, arg):
        days = []
        if language == "ru":
            if arg == 'weeks':
                days = ['неделя', 'недели', 'недель']
            elif arg == 'days':
                days = ['день', 'дня', 'дней']
            elif arg == 'hours':
                days = ['час', 'часа', 'часов']
            elif arg == 'minutes':
                days = ['минута', 'минуты', 'минут']
            elif arg == 'seconds':
                days = ['секунда', 'секунды', 'секунд']
        elif language == "en":
            if arg == 'weeks':
                days = ['week', 'weeks', 'weeks']        
            elif arg == 'days':
                days = ['day', 'day', 'days']
            elif arg == 'hours':
                days = ['hour', 'hour', 'hours']
            elif arg == 'minutes':
                days = ['minute', 'minute', 'minutes']
            elif arg == 'seconds':
                days = ['second', 'second', 'seconds']

        if n % 10 == 1 and n % 100 != 11:
            p = 0
        elif 2 <= n % 10 <= 4 and (n % 100 < 10 or n % 100 >= 20):
            p = 1
        else:
            p = 2
        return str(n) + ' ' + days[p]

    counter_in_str = ""
    for i in timestr_to_dict(str_time).items():
        counter_in_str += f"{plural(i[1], i[0])} "

    return int(timestr_to_seconds(str_time)), counter_in_str

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def оффлайн(ctx):
    await bot.change_presence(status = ds.Status.invisible)   

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def онлайн(ctx):
    await bot.change_presence(status = ds.Status.online

@bot.command(aliases = ['бан'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def ban(ctx, member: ds.Member, time, reason):
  await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} **забанен** \n Продолжительность бана: *{time}* \n Причина бана: *{reason}*')
  await member.send(f'Тебя забанили на {time} на сервере {ctx.guild.name} по причине {reason}')
  await member.ban(reason=reason)
  seconds, str_time = str_time_to_seconds(time)
  await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
  await member.unban()
  await ctx.send(f'*У {member.mention} закончился бан*')
  link = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_age=300)
  await member.send(f'У тебя закончился бан на сервере "{ctx.guild.name}"! {link}')

@bot.command()
async def рандом(ctx, par):
  r=par.split('-')
  await ctx.send(random.randint(int(r[0]), int(r[1])))

@bot.command(aliases = ['размут', 'размьют'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def unmute(ctx, member: ds.Member):
  mute_role = ds.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = 'Mute')
  await member.remove_roles(mute_role)
  await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} *больше не замучен.*')

@bot.command(aliases = ['мут', 'мьют'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def mute(ctx, user: ds.Member, time, reason):
  role = ds.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = 'Mute')
  await ctx.send(f'**{user.mention} замучен** \n Продолжительность мута: *{time}* \n Причина: *{reason}*')
  await user.add_roles(role)
  await user.move_to(None)
  seconds, str_time = str_time_to_seconds(time)
  await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
  await user.remove_roles(role)
  await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} *больше не замучен*')

#команда unban

@bot.command()
async def инфо(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Я первый бот от S_Smerch, я пока мало обучен. Но обещаю что буду в будущем содержать в себе много функций!')

@bot.command()
async def пинг(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Понг!')

@bot.command()
async def бот(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Сам такой!')

@bot.command()
async def помощь(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Все команды: \n **`!помощь`**  -  вы только что прописали эту команду  :) \n **`!инфо`**  -  информация о боте \n **`!пинг`**  -  понг! \n **`!бот`**  -  вы обидете бота  :( \n **`!рандом [число]-[число]`**  -  случайное число \n **`!мут @member`**  -  мутит человека *(команда для админа)* \n **`!бан [@member] [time] [причина]`** -  \n \n Остались вопросы? Пиши на `TT | _#2902`!')

keep_alive()
bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

Всё было хорошо, но перестал работать `async def <команда>`
Теперь выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
File "main.py", line 127
    async def ban(ctx, member: ds.Member, time, reason):
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

И так не только с командой бан, но и с другими...

Почему не работает? Мой дс: `TT | S_Smerch#2902`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы забыли приписать скобку в строке:

 await bot.change_presence(status = ds.Status.online`)`

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def онлайн(ctx):
    await bot.change_presence(status = ds.Status.online)
```

Comment: ппц, протупил...